# Appharbor cloudinary upload form

Tags: forms, asp.net-mvc-4, appharbor, cloudinary

I'm trying to make a form where I can register and upload an image chosen by the user as their profile picture.

I'm following these instructions: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/appharbor_integration

At the moment I think I got everything running.

What I don't know is how to make a file input tag that communicates with the cloudinary to upload the image.

In here: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/cloudcontrol_integration

They explain on PHP, Ruby&Rails and DJango but no ASP.NET MVC4.

Is there a way I can make a form so it uploads directly to the cloudinary?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at Cloudinary's .NET documentation regarding direct client-side uploads here: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_image_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser.

Also, you can try out the sample projects:
https://github.com/cloudinary/CloudinaryDotNet/tree/master/samples